# srand() is not working below initialization of array randomly

Tags: c, random, srand

Below but it always gives me 42 as SIZE. I wanted to randomise SIZE with srand(time(NULL)) but obviously it is not working because it is below randomisation of SIZE. When I try to add it before randomization of SIZE, compiler yells at me. Do you have any ideas how to correct it?

```
int i,numberToBeFound;
int SIZE=(rand()%100)+1; // size can be in the range [1 to 100]
int *array2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);

srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)     //fill the array with random numbers
    array2[i]=rand()%100;
```

Comment: Call `srand` _before_ you use `rand()`.

Comment: It gives me 15 errors and 9 warnings If I do it

Comment: I think the errors he's seeing are code before declaration when he moves srand above rand.

Comment: That's because the compiler doesn't accept mixed declarations and code (C89, blech). Declare all variables first.

Comment: If you were working in C++, it would have worked moving the seeding of srand() up before you needed to call rand(). But in C, it is declare all locals before doing code statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `srand()` **before** you call `rand()` to initialize the random number generator.

You can try `srand( time( NULL ) )` which will give you a different result once per second. If you need it to be more variable than that, then you will have to come up with a better way to seed the number generator.

```
int i,numberToBeFound;
int SIZE;
int *array2;

srand( time( NULL ) );

SIZE=(rand()%100)+1; // size can be in the range [1 to 100]
array2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)     //fill the array with random numbers
    array2[i]=rand()%100;
```

PS: You should not cast `malloc()` in C -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: He does call `srand(time(NULL))`; the problem is that he does it *after* calling `rand()` to initialize `SIZE`. (Your code calls `srand()` twice, which is rarely a good idea.)

Comment: Ah... doh. I didn't look past the `rand()` call once I saw he hadn't called `srand()` yet. ~lol~ Edited accordingly.

Comment: I already know that I have to call srand before rand but because I am using Visual Studio, when I put srand before rand, compiler does not accept it. I asked if there is a workaround of this.

Comment: seriously? Edited to declare the variables first, then call srand(), then init the variables. I'm stunned you couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
int i, numberToBeFound;
int SIZE=0;
int* array2=0;

srand(time(NULL));

SIZE=(rand()%100)+1; // size can be in the range [1 to 100]
array2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)     //fill the array with random numbers
    array2[i]=rand()%100;
```

It is ancient C (C89 or older). So declare your locals, then init them, and finally use them as needed.

Comment: this still does not randomize SIZE, because the seed is done after the rand call.

Comment: You still call `rand()` before `srand()`. And it's not C, it's C89 [obsolete, invalidated, bad].

Comment: That's not the issue... the issue is that he didn't call `srand()` **before** he called `rand()`

Comment: No, this is the issue, just OP didn't make it clear, see his comment on other answer.

Comment: It is the issue. It is C, not C++. I just forgot to move the srand seeding call up. Code block edited to reflect the correct order. Declare locals, initialize. Use. That is C.

Comment: The current C standard permits mixed declarations and statements within a block; that's been the case since 1999.  The OP is probably using a compiler that only supports C90. @DanielFischer: the code is still valid C99 and C11; refraining from using C99 features doesn't make it "not C".

Comment: The `malloc` call is better written as `array2 = malloc(SIZE * sizeof *array2);`

Comment: @KeithThompson Valid points. But in older C standards, you declare all local variables first. Since the OP stated he moved the call to seed rand before the declares and his compiler screamed at him, that allowed us to deduce his compiler is using and older standard.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio you are right I will immediately change it Poor Microsoft

Comment: @KeithThompson Sure the code is valid C. I referred to "It is c. So declare your locals, then init and set them as needed." which I interpret as meaning that C doesn't allow mixed declarations and code. And it is not C that is forbidding mixed declarations and code, but C89. (cf. also [this comment by StarPilot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345288/srand-is-not-working-below-initialization-of-array-randomly/16345354?noredirect=1#comment23414504_16345288) that seems to imply that (s)he believes C forbids it.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok, it wasn't clear (to me) what "it" referred to in "it's not C". I agree with your point. Unfortunately, not everyone has the luxury of using up-to-date compilers.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll update my "it's c" statement to make you happy.

Comment: You didn't have to include the "ancient", saying C89 is enough. Now I can upvote the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You say in a comment that if you call `srand()` before `rand()`, your compiler doesn't accept it.

That's because your compiler (Microsoft?) is enforcing C89/C90 rules, which don't permit declarations to follow statements within a block.

You can work around that limitation by adding a new block.  A rough outline:

```
srand(time(NULL));
{
     int size = rand() % 100 + 1;
     /* ... */
}
```

Or you can remove the initializers for `size` and `array2`, replacing them with assignments after calling `srand()`. Personally, I prefer to initialize variables as early as possible.

Generally speaking, you should call `srand()` exactly once in your program, before any calls to `rand()`. (That's for the most general case where you want non-repeating pseudo-random numbers; if you actually need a repeatable sequence, a different strategy is appropriate.)

(Without a call to `srand()`, `rand()` behaves as if you had called `srand(1)`, and generates the same sequence each time.)

(I've changed the name of your variable `SIZE` to `size`; all-caps identifiers are conventionally used for macros.)

Comment: that function creation of srand was genius as a workaround. Thanks

Comment: @user1939432: That's not "function creation", I just added a block. Syntactically, `{` followed by zero or more declarations and statements followed by `}` is a compound statement, which can appear anywhere a statement can appear *or* as the body of a function. In C90, declarations must precede statements within a block; in C99 and later (and in C++) they can be mixed.

Answer (score 1):

To not get always the same result from `rand` you need to seed the generator with `srand` before doing any calls to `rand`. So you only need to move your `srand` call to a place before calling `rand`.